# perl regex, replace each individual words with another one

Tags: regex, perl

I have a formulat like

```
(var1  - var2 ) + var3
```

I want to replace `var1 - var 3` with

```
(put(var1,format.) - put(var2, format.) + put(var3, format.)
```

what is the simplest way to do that with perl reg?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = '(var1 - var2 ) + var3';
$string  =~ s/\b(var\d+)\b/put($1, format.)/g;
print $string;
```

Comment: `\1` is a regex pattern that matches that contents of `$1`. It makes no sense to use it outside of a regular expression. Fixed.

Comment: thanks!how to handle the situation like this: we don't know how many vars ( it may be 2, or 3 o4 4 or 5), also, we dont know if there is a - or + or / or * operation.  How to handle this generalized situation?

Comment: @john, No change whatsoever is needed to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $string = '(var1 - var2 ) + var3';
$string  =~ s/(var\d+)/put($1, format.)/g;
print $string;
```